# copy build from containter in different context

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

So im trying to get the environment for my project set up to use docker. Project structure is as follows.

```
/client
/server
/nginx
docker-compose.yml
docker-compose.override.yml
docker-compose.prod.yml
```

in the `Dockerfile` for each `/client`, `/server`, and `nginx` I have a base image that installs my dependencies then a development image that installs dev-dependencies and a production image that builds or runs the image for client and server respectively

ex.

```
# start from a node image
FROM node:14.8.0-alpine as base
WORKDIR /client
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm i --only=prod

FROM base as development
RUN npm install --only=dev
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]

FROM base as production
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

so here is where my problem comes in.
In `/nginx` I want nginx in development just act as a revers proxy for create-react-app, but when I am in production I want to take `client/build` from the production client image and copy it into the nginx server to be served statically without the overhead of the entire build tool chain for react.

ie.

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as base

FROM base as development
COPY development.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

FROM base as production
COPY production.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=??? /client/build /usr/share/nginx/html
             ^
      what goes here?
```

If anyone has any clue how to get this to work without having pull from docker hub and having to push images up to docker hub every time a change is made that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can `COPY --from=` another image by name.  Just like `docker run`, the image needs to be local, and Docker won't contact Docker Hub or another registry server if you already have the image.

```sh
# Most basic form; "myapp" is the containing directory name
COPY --from=myapp_client /client/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Compose doesn't directly have a way to specify this build dependency, but running `docker-compose build` twice should do the trick.

If you're planning to deploy this, you probably want some control over the name and tag of the image.  In `docker-compose.yml` you can specify both [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) and [`image:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#image), which well tell Compose what name to use when it builds the image.  You can also [use environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) almost everywhere in the Compose file, and pass [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) into a build to configure it.  Combining all of these would give you:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  client:
    build: ./client
    image: registry.example.com/my/client:${TAG:-latest}
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      args:
        TAG: ${TAG:-latest}
    image: registry.example.com/my/client:${TAG:-latest}
```

```sh
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
ARG TAG=latest
COPY --from=registry.example.com/my/client:${TAG} /usr/share/nginx/html
```

```sh
TAG=20210113 docker-compose build
TAG=20210113 docker-compose build
TAG=20210113 docker-compose up -d
# TAG=20210113 docker-compose push
```